# optional arguments of functions in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write slicing code which gets a linked list, start,stop, step.
My code is supposed to behave like same as using `list[start:step:stop]`.

My problem starts when the user insert only 1 argument (let's says it was *x*) - then,
*x* is supposed to get into `stop` and and not `start`. But, I have been told that optional 
arguments need to appear at the end of all the arguments.

Can someone tell me how can we insert only 1 input to the second argument while the first
one is mandatory but the second one is not?
By the way, i can't use built-in functions

Comment: Isn’t it ``start:stop:step``?

Comment: Try to use `Keyword` arguements, where you can specify `key=value` type of arguements, and limit your `positional/mandatory` arguement inside your `function/method`

Comment: I can't use built-in functions.. that is the idea of the assigment. I will add this info to the description

Comment: Siva, can you give me a simple example?

Comment: @user3130794, Please see the Answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using optional (named) arguments:

```
def foo(start, stop=None, step=1):
    if stop == None:
        start, stop = 0, start
    #rest of the code goes here
```

Then `foo(5) == foo(0,5,1)`, but `foo(1,5) == foo(1,5,1)`. I think this works, anyway... :)

Comment: I'd use `None` as sentinel, this will make things much clearer.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a LinkedList class that defines the **__*getitem*__** function to get access to python's notation.

```
class LinkedList:

    # Implement the Linked ...

    def __getitem__(self, slice):

        start = slice.start
        stop = slice.stop
        step = slice.step

        # Implement the function
```

Then you can use LinkedList like you want

```
l = LinkedList()
l[1]
l[1:10]
l[1:10:2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
def myF(*args):
    number_args = len(args)
    if number_args == 1:
        stop = ...
    elif number_args == 2:
        ...
    elif number_args == 3:
        ...
    else
        print "Error"
```

`*args` means that the arguments passed to the function `myF` will be stored in the variable `args`.

Comment: The number of arguments is `len(args)`. Read more about this on Internet. @volcano this is just an example.

Comment: What If he passes 2 arguments and the very first one is supposed to be mandatory ???

Comment: @Crhistian, read about DRY on inetrnet. Even example should demonstrate efficient code

Comment: @volcano edited. @ Siva Cn I don't understand, maybe my bad English, can you give an example?

Comment: incredible.Didn't know I could do that. Thanks!

Comment: @Christian, In this case the arguments are `start, stop and step` in the same order, You are just checking the length of the arguments, where in, the `start/stop` is mandatory

Comment: I'm assuming that the user won't use `myF(stop, start)`. I don't think it's necessary to check. As you don't use for example `str[stop:start]`

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None):
    if not arg1:
        print 'arg1 is mandatory'
        return False
    ## do your stuff here

arg1 = 1
arg2 = 4
arg3 = 1

## works fine
func(arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2, arg3=arg3)

## Evaluated as False, Since the first argument is missing
func(arg2=arg2, arg3=arg3)
```